# "workers and intellectuals who led the October 1917 Revolution and created the Soviet Union"

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

*The publication of the English-language edition of Stalin’s Terror of 1937-1938: Political Genocide in the USSR by the late Marxist historian and sociologist Vadim Rogovin is a major contribution to the study of the purges that wiped out the entire generation of Bolshevik leaders and socialist workers and intellectuals who **led** the October 1917 Revolution and **created** the Soviet Union.*

Source: https://www.wsws.org/en/articles/2009/09/rogo-s09.html

Do you think that it would be a mistake if there would be used the past perfect in bold passages? The October Revolution and the creation of the Soviet Union happened before the political trials. Or is the simple past used because of the minimal time interval between the two mentioned events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> wiped out ... those who led
>
> wiped out ... those who had led

The past perfect could certainly be used but it's not necessary.

As to why the author didn't use it, that's hard to say. The sentence is clear enough without it, and  I doubt that the choice had anything to do with the amount of time that had elapsed between the purges and the revolution.

Answer (score 0):

There would be nothing wrong with using the pluperfect here, but it is not necessary.

Both "led" and "created" are part of a relative subordinate clause.

Had the sentence read "those who were purged had led the Revolution and had created the Soviet Union" - then the pluperfect would have been essential